# Read file with random number of whitespaces

Tags: r, read.table, readr

I need to read several files that have a random number of whitespaces as separator.

The data always has 4 columns and is always seperated by `Whitespace > 1`.

`Whitespace = 1` is used in the columns as a normal whitespace but is not a sepatator.

Data

```
File                     Name          Time                        Status
Let_L12M.xlsm            NameA NameAB  2021-02-09 13:15:50         open
Let_L12M.xlsm            NameC NameCA NameCB             2021-05-10 07:19:21         open
Let_L12M.xlsm            NameD NameDA NameDB             2021-05-10 07:21:35         open
Let_L12M.xlsm            NameA NameAB  2021-05-10 11:11:23         open
```

I've tried variations of `strip.white.space`, `read_table`, `gsub` and more, but can't get it to work.

Comment: You should complain to whoever is responsible for creating the code producing these files. That should never have passed code review.

Comment: Is it tab separated?

Comment: No, it is random white space separated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Replace repetitions of 2 or more spaces with comma and read in as a csv.

```
# L <- readLines("myfile.txt")
L <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))
read.csv(text = gsub("  +", ",", L))
```

giving:

```
           File                Name                Time Status
1 Let_L12M.xlsm        NameA NameAB 2021-02-09 13:15:50   open
2 Let_L12M.xlsm NameC NameCA NameCB 2021-05-10 07:19:21   open
3 Let_L12M.xlsm NameD NameDA NameDB 2021-05-10 07:21:35   open
4 Let_L12M.xlsm        NameA NameAB 2021-05-10 11:11:23   open
```

**2)** Because there is a pattern to the internal spaces, i.e. the fields have 0, ?, 1 and 0 spaces internally respectively, we could alternately parse it with a regular expression.  As long as this pattern holds this would work even if the fields were separated by only one space.   In this case we handle the header separately.  Replace `text=Lines` with your filename as in the comment in (1) to use with a file.

```
library(gsubfn)

pat <- "^(\\S+) +(.*) +(\\S+ \\S+) +(\\S+)$"
read.pattern(text = Lines, pattern = pat, skip = 1,
  col.names = read.table(text = Lines, nrow = 1))
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "File                     Name          Time                        Status
Let_L12M.xlsm            NameA NameAB  2021-02-09 13:15:50         open
Let_L12M.xlsm            NameC NameCA NameCB             2021-05-10 07:19:21         open
Let_L12M.xlsm            NameD NameDA NameDB             2021-05-10 07:21:35         open
Let_L12M.xlsm            NameA NameAB  2021-05-10 11:11:23         open"
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the input with the file name:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("File                     Name          Time                        Status
Let_L12M.xlsm            NameA NameAB  2021-02-09 13:15:50         open
Let_L12M.xlsm            NameC NameCA NameCB             2021-05-10 07:19:21         open
Let_L12M.xlsm            NameD NameDA NameDB             2021-05-10 07:21:35         open
Let_L12M.xlsm            NameA NameAB  2021-05-10 11:11:23         open", 
   sep = "", skip = 1, header = FALSE)

DT <- DT[, tstrsplit(V1, " {2,}")] #match two or more blanks

setnames(DT, unlist(fread("File                     Name          Time                        Status
Let_L12M.xlsm            NameA NameAB  2021-02-09 13:15:50         open
Let_L12M.xlsm            NameC NameCA NameCB             2021-05-10 07:19:21         open
Let_L12M.xlsm            NameD NameDA NameDB             2021-05-10 07:21:35         open
Let_L12M.xlsm            NameA NameAB  2021-05-10 11:11:23         open", 
   nrows = 1, header = FALSE)))

DT
#            File                Name                Time Status
#1: Let_L12M.xlsm        NameA NameAB 2021-02-09 13:15:50   open
#2: Let_L12M.xlsm NameC NameCA NameCB 2021-05-10 07:19:21   open
#3: Let_L12M.xlsm NameD NameDA NameDB 2021-05-10 07:21:35   open
#4: Let_L12M.xlsm        NameA NameAB 2021-05-10 11:11:23   open
```